# Arranging Letters and Plus Signs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

We have 4 spaces which should be filled with $1$ letter and $3$ plus signs, $2$ letters and $2$ plus signs, or with $3$ letters and $1$ plus sign. In any of these cases, letters can not be repeated and their orders  and positions matter, and the plus signs are identical so their order does not matter.

Examples of valid arrangements:

++CY, +AT+, +++S, WXY+

Examples of invalid arrangements:

+++SA (we have exactly 4 spaces), U+JU (letters can not be repeated), AZQC (not satisfying any of the three given cases, note that the 4 spaces is neither letters only nor plus signs only).

Note: A+B+ and A++B are different since the positions of the letters matter.

> How many different arrangements are there?

Clearly, for the first scenario (using $1$ letter and $3$ plus signs) we have $26\times4=104$ different arrangements. I am confused with the second and the third scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

For the second scenario, think of it this way:

- First, you **choose** the $2$ positions that will contain the letters
- Then, you **arrange** two letters on the two chosen positions.

Comment: I already tried this way. The confusion here is: not only the order of the letters matters, but the positions also. 2 letters can be permuted in $26P2 = 26\times 25 = 650$ ways. But what about the positions?!

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Did you even read my answer? The positions matter, that's why I told you you first CHOOSE the positions. How many ways can you choose two positions out of 4?

Comment: Yes dear, I have read your answer. But I am confusing if this way will not count the all possible arrangements. I am confusing if this way will count ++YZ and +Y+Z as one arrangement.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari How many ways can you **choose** two positions out of 4?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari  This method will not count ++YZ and +Y+Z as one arrangement.  To obtain ++YZ, you must first choose the third and fourth positions for the letters in step 1, then choose Y and Z in that order in the second step.  To obtain +Y+Z, you must first choose the second and fourth positions for the letters in step 1, then choose Y and Z in that order in the second step.  Choosing the positions in the first step distinguishes between those arrangements.

Comment: @5xum I can choose $2$ positions out of $4$ in $({4 \times 3})/({1 \times 2}) = 6$ ways.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I come up with the following result: $(26C1)(4P1)+(26C2)(4P2)+(26C3)(4P3)=66404$ different arrangements. Am I right?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari That's correct.